# Webforms - RadiobuttonLists client side click event not working

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, webforms

I have a server side `RadioButtonList` control that renders client side code as below. As you can see, I have attached client side javascript to show an alert when any of the radio buttons are clicked. This is in line with the examples I saw online. However, the alert doesn't show when I click any radio button. The console doesnt show any errors either. What could be wrong? I can only use pure javascript and not jQuery. I am running this in the latest Chrome browser.

```
<span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_rblApartmentType">
    <input id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_rblApartmentType_0" type="radio" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$rblApartmentType" value="1" onclick="javascript:alert('1');">
    <label for="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_rblApartmentType_0">Apartment</label>
    <input id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_rblApartmentType_1" type="radio" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$rblApartmentType" value="2" onclick="javascript:alert('2');">
    <label for="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_rblApartmentType_1">Town Home</label>
    <input id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_rblApartmentType_2" type="radio" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$rblApartmentType" value="3" checked="checked" onclick="javascript:alert('3');">
    <label for="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_rblApartmentType_2">Condo</label>
</span>
```

Comment: This example works for me.. :thinking-face:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/POMbqo

Comment: This guy says use onClick >> https://juristr.com/blog/2008/06/attaching-client-side-event-handler-to/ but I can't get it to work with onClick. It worked using onChange! :/

Comment: Since we do not have access to your server side stuff, I would recommend you spending some time learning the developer tools :) Try to inspect the current element after the server-side has generated the code. See if the onClick element is present.

Comment: yes it is present :)  That code in question above is what is rendered down in the client.

Comment: How about posting the ENTIRE rendered page?

Comment: Well, if that is rendered on to the dom... It should work :/ I don't think we can help you further without more code

Comment: My radiobuttonlist renders in a table.

Answer (score 0):

not necessarily an answer, but for viewing, cuz there's s/t weird with the op's rendering:

page:

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem Text="a" Value="1" onclick="alert('1');"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="b" Value="2" onclick="alert('2');"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

renders as:

```
<table id="RadioButtonList1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input id="RadioButtonList1_0" type="radio"
          name="ctl00$MainContent$RadioButtonList1" value="1" onclick="alert('1');">
        <label for="RadioButtonList1_0">a</label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input id="RadioButtonList1_1" type="radio"
          name="ctl00$MainContent$RadioButtonList1" value="2" onclick="alert('2');">
        <label for="RadioButtonList1_1">b</label></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

note, i also use this in web.config so the IDs aren't so crazy when rendered (gets rid of a lot of stuff like `ctl00$...`:

```
<system.web>
  <pages clientIDMode="Static">
```